# unsigned to signed conversion

Tags: c++

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    unsigned int x = 3;
    unsigned int y = 5;

    std::cout << "a: " << x - y        << std::endl;

    std::cout << "b: " << ((int)x) - y << std::endl;

    std::cout << "c: " << x - ((int)y) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "d: " << ((int)x) - ((int)y) << std::endl;

}

$ g++ -Wconversion -Wall uint_stackoverflow.cc -o uint_stackoverflow && ./uint_stackoverflow
a: 4294967294
b: 4294967294
c: 4294967294
d: -2
```

I understand why "a" doesn't give the expected result. But why "b" and "c" fail puzzles me. For "b" I thought after casting "x" to "int" the result will be "int" again.

Could you please enlighten me?

edit: Shouldn't the compiler warn? g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5

Thanks,

Somebody

Answer (score 28):

In arithmetic operations, if any of the operand is `unsigned`, the *other* operand converts to `unsigned` (if its `signed`), and the result of the operations will be `unsigned` also.

Also, casting `unsigned` to `signed` and then doing the operation doesn't change the bit representation of the operand. On a two's complement architecture (i.e *almost* every modern architecture), `(int)x` has same bit representation as `x` has, only their interpretation changes when calculating their *value* in decimal system. But the important point is that the arithmetic operation is performed on the bit representations (**not** on their *values* in decimal system). And since the casting doesn't change the bit representation, the bit representation of the result will also NOT change.

C++03 Standard says in §5/9:

> Many binary operators that expect
>   operands of arithmetic or enumeration
>   type cause conversions and yield
>   result types in a similar way. The
>   purpose is to yield a common type,
>   which is also the type of the result.
>   This pattern is called the usual
>   arithmetic conversions, which are
>   defined as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> Otherwise, **if either operand is
>   unsigned, the other shall be converted
>   to unsigned**.

Comment: Note that converting large `unsigned` to `signed` is explicitly non-portable. The C++11 standard says: "If the destination type is signed, the value does not change if the source integer can be represented in the destination type. **Otherwise the result is implementation-defined.**"

Comment: Arithmetic is performed on *values* in C, not bit representations per se.   One of the advantages of choose two's complement representation is that signed arithmetic can be done using the same instructions as for unsigned.  It has nothing to do with whether casting changes the representation though, really, this has to work the same on systems that don't use 2's complement.

Comment: In the first para it'd be good to clarify that you mean `unsigned int` specifically and not unsigned types in general  (e.g. if `unsigned short` and `short` are the operands then they promote to `int`, not anything unsigned)

Answer (score 12):

Quoting the standard as usual....

For C++98, **§[expr]/9:**

> Many binary operators that expect
>   operands of arithmetic or enumeration
>   type cause conversions and yield
>   result types in a similar way. The
>   purpose is to yield a common type,
>   which is also the type of the result.
>   This pattern is called the *usual
>   arithmetic conversions*, which are
>   defined as follows:
>
> - If either operand is of type `long double`, the other shall be converted
>     to `long double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, the other shall be converted
>     to `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `float`, the other shall be converted
>     to `float`.
> - Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both
>     operands.<sup>54)</sup>
> - Then, if either operand is `unsigned long` the other shall be converted to
>     `unsigned long`.
> - Otherwise, if one operand is a `long int` and the other `unsigned int`,
>     then if a `long int` can represent all
>     the values of an `unsigned int`, the
>     `unsigned int` shall be converted to a
>     `long int`; otherwise both operands
>     shall be converted to `unsigned long
>     int`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `long`, the other shall be converted
>     to `long`.
> - **Otherwise, if either operand is `unsigned`, the other shall be
>     converted to `unsigned`.**
>
> [Note: otherwise, the only remaining
>   case is that both operands are `int` ]

Basically, it can be summarized as

- `long double` > `double` > `float` > `unsigned long` > `long` > `unsigned` > `int`
- (Types smaller than `int` will be converted to `int`)

The text is changed for C++0x (§[expr]/10) after the 5th item, but the effect on OP's code is the same: the `int` will be converted to an `unsigned`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because there is a heirarchy of data types when performing implicit conversions, unsigned integers have a higher precedence than signed integers so b and c are being cast back to unsigned integers which is why you're seeing the results you are.

If you are unsure of the types but know the type of the result you want then you should cast both x and y as you did in d.

This has a really good explanation of type conversion:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/44-type-conversion-and-casting/