# Can I use a signed integer as an argument to __builtin_popcount()?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gnu

This site: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html says that it is defined for unsigned integers. Will using it for signed int give wrong results in some cases or not?

Comment: Maybe. If it says it is only defined for unsigned, signed may work or not. Don´t rely on it.

Comment: Why not just cast to `unsigned int` (an operation which is completely well-defined by the language) before calling it? Do you intend to pass negative numbers, and if so what answer do you want?

Answer (score 5):

`__builtin_popcount` is a gcc-specific extension. It acts like a function with the declaration:

```
int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x);
```

If you had an actual function with that declaration, *and* its declaration were visible, then you could pass an argument of any numeric type to it. Since the declaration is a prototype, any argument you pass would be implicitly converted to the parameter type, `unsigned int`.

Conversion from (signed) `int` to `unsigned int` is well defined. If the value being converted is within the range `0` .. `INT_MAX`, the value is unchanged. Otherwise, it's wrapped module `UINT_MAX+1`. For example, converting `-1` to `unsigned int` yields `UINT_MAX`, which is 2<sup>32</sup>-1 if `unsigned int` is 32 bits wide.

So the question is, does gcc treat `__builtin_popcount` as a function with a visible prototype? Since it's a language extension, it doesn't *have* to, and the gcc manual isn't entirely clear. It shows a prototype for it, but that doesn't *necessarily* mean that prototype is visible to your code.

An experiment with gcc 4.8.2 indicates that it is treated as a function with a visible prototype. (You can't store its address in a pointer as you could for an ordinary function, but that shouldn't be a problem).  This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    unsigned int n = 21845; // 0x5555, popcount = 8
    float        x = 21845.0;
    unsigned int x_rep;
    memcpy(&x_rep, &x, sizeof x_rep);

    if (sizeof x != sizeof x_rep) {
        puts("WARNING: Sizes do not match");
    }
    printf("popcount(%u) = %d\n", n, __builtin_popcount(n));
    printf("popcount(%g) = %d\n", x, __builtin_popcount(x));
    printf("popcount(%u) = %d\n", x_rep, __builtin_popcount(x_rep));
    return 0;
}
```

produces this output on my system:

```
popcount(21845) = 8
popcount(21845) = 8
popcount(1185589760) = 11
```

Which means that the value of `x` is converted to `unsigned int`, not just reinterpreted. When we explicitly reinterpret its representation, we get different results.

So unless gcc changes its implementation of builtin functions for some reason (that seems unlikely), passing a signed `int` to `__builtin_popcount` should work as expected, converting the `int` value to `unsigned int`. And assuming a 2's-complement representation for signed integers (which is a reasonably safe assumption), converting from `int` to `unsigned int` does not change the representation, so `__builtin_popcount` will give you a correct count of the bits that are set in the representation of the `int`, including the sign bit.

Of course if you don't want to depend on this, you can always explicitly convert the value to `unsigned int` using a cast. Casts are often error-prone, and it's *usually* better to use implicit conversions, but in this case it might be a reasonable approach.

Having said all this, if you're computing the population count of a value, it almost certainly makes more sense to start with an unsigned value. It's likely that the signed `int` value you're passing to `__builtin_popcount` *should* have been defined as an `unsigned int` in the first place.

Finally, you wrote that `__builtin_popcount` is "defined for unsigned integers". Actually, it's defined only for type `unsigned int`, not for unsigned integers in general. There are three different builtin functions:

```
int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x);
int __builtin_popcountl (unsigned long x);
int __builtin_popcountll (unsigned long long x);
```

You need to use the right one for the type of data you're working with. Using `__builtin_popcount` on an `unsigned long long` object will likely ignore the upper half of the value, probably without a warning from the compiler.

Comment: But why does this function not perform implicit type conversion?
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount

Comment: @fqq That was added to the language in C++20. The standard specifically says that it's constrained to operate only on unsigned integer types.

Answer (score 3):

To complement the other answers, here is a do-it-yourself, what-is-gcc-doing example. Let us write a simple testcase:

```
int f(int i){
  return __builtin_popcount(i);
}
```

and compile it with `gcc -c test.c -fdump-tree-all`. This creates several files, starting with `test.c.003t.original`:

```
;; Function f (null)
;; enabled by -tree-original

{
  return __builtin_popcount ((unsigned int) i);
}
```

So you can see that when `__builtin_popcount` is called on a signed integer, gcc casts it to the documented argument type of `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can pass `signed int` as well — *assuming negative number is  represented as 2's complement (which is most on the modern systems)*.

If the number is positive, then it is as good as `unsigned int`.  If you pass a negative number however, say `-1`, it will convert into a very large number of type `unsigned int`, **but it will not  change the bits-pattern — hence the number of bits**. `signed` or `unsigned` has nothing to do with bit-patterns, it has to do [the interpretation of bits-pattern when computing value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5800976/415784).

```
signed int i = -1;    //i has N number of 1 bit
unsigned int j = -1;  //j has N number of 1 bit as well.
                      //j becomes a very large number!
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don´t think that´s generally valid, eg. Section 4.7 ([conv.integral]). And it´s not even guaranteed that __builtin_something behaves like a normal function with unsigned parameter.

Comment: @deviantfan: I added *"assuming negative number is represented as 2's compliment (which is most on the systems)."*

Comment: This assumes that the compiler provides the equivalent of a visible prototype for `__builtin_popcount`. It turns out that it does, but that's not 100% clear from the documentation.